# Binding to Class Item

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

This seems like it should be really basic but I can't seemto get it working.

I have a class file called XMLSource as follows:

```vb
Public Class XMLSource

    Public Shared BrandItems As New MediaItems

    Public Class MediaItems
        Inherits ObservableCollection(Of MediaObject)
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged   
    End Class
End Class

Public Class MediaObject
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Title As String
End Class
```

The application reads an XML file and stores some items into XMLSource.BrandItems (happens on start-up).

I want to bind a Label control's Content property to XMLSource.BrandItems(0).Name

I tried:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={XMLSource},Path=.BrandItems[0].Src}" FontSize="20"></Label>
```

But it's not working.

Is it possible to bind directly like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot contruct bindings like this, if you write `{}` that indicates a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx), further you cannot have static/shared members in a binding path. I think the correct binding would be:

```xml
{Binding [0].Src, Source={x:Static ns:XMLSource.BrandItems}}
```

[`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) is a markup extension which allows access of static members. (Note that this also allows access of fields unlike the `Path` which only allows public properties)

Where `ns` is declared in an [`xmlns` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) and points to the namespace of your `XMLSource` class.